# How to clone and extend to new disk in FreeBSD?

Tags: partition, freebsd, hard-disk

A server running FreeBSD has been in production since ~2004. Recently there was a power outage and upon reboot it displays an error message "...filesystem full".

It was on a 40 GB drive from back then, grabbed a 1 TB to replace it. Copied the drive with dd then tried Gparted but it seems to not recognize the filesystem.

Question - what is the simplest way to clone the old drive and resize the partitions to use the full space of the new drive?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `gpart` (not gparted) to create partitions and then put a file systems on the new partition using `newfs`. Then use `dump | restore` or `rsync` to copy the data to the new disk. Finally, use `gpart` to ensure there's boot code on the drive. See the man pages for these commands for more detail.

A note though, given the question, I'm guessing the OS hasn't been updated since 2004 and is no longer supported and not getting security updates. So really, you're better off installing a new system on the new disk and then using `dump | restore` or `rsync` or `cp` to manually copy relevant data to the new disk. I do not recommend putting the OS from 2004 back into production.

Comment: Good point, it has not been updated. I'll give the new install a shot via live usb, will be working with my laptop and the new drive til I have access to the physical server tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

I just did this, although to a disk of the same size with a slightly smaller / filesystem.  I'm pretty sure the procedure will work with a larger disk.

```
# newdisk=ada1
# echo $newdisk
ada1
# gpart create -s GPT $newdisk
# gpart add -t freebsd-boot -i 1 -a 4K -s 512K -l gptboot ${newdisk}
ada1p1 added
# gpart bootcode -p /boot/gptboot -i 1 ${newdisk}
partcode written to ada1p1
# gpart add -t freebsd-ufs -a 4K -s 70G -i 2 -l fbsdroot $newdisk
ada1p2 added
# gpart add -t freebsd-swap -a 4K -i 3 -l fbsdswap $newdisk
ada1p3 added
# gpart show
=>       34  156249933  ada0  GPT  (75G)
         34       1024     1  freebsd-boot  (512K)
       1058  148896768     2  freebsd-ufs  (71G)
  148897826    7352140     3  freebsd-swap  (3.5G)
  156249966          1        - free -  (512B)

=>       40  156301408  ada1  GPT  (75G)
         40       1024     1  freebsd-boot  (512K)
       1064  156300384     2  freebsd-ufs  (75G)

=>       40  156301408  diskid/DISK-5JVD21RN  GPT  (75G)
         40       1024                     1  freebsd-boot  (512K)
       1064  146800640                     2  freebsd-ufs  (70G)
  146801704    9499744                     3  freebsd-swap  (4.5G)
# newfs -U /dev/ada1p2
...
# mkdir /mnt/newsys
Reboot system into single-user mode; it should come up read-only
# mount /dev/ada1p2 /mnt/newsys
# cd /mnt/newsys
dump -0 -f - /dev/ada0p2 | restore -r -Dv -f -
```

My original system disk had unrecoverable bad blocks; the new sys is clean.  I was lucky, as the bad blocks were in unused files in /var/db/freebsd-update/files/ and that whole directory is no longer needed (backup from a system update 6 months ago).